# How to select X grid points from specific grid location in xarray?

Tags: numpy, python-xarray

Assuming I have a dataset `ds` with coordinates and dimensions defined as `['time','lat','lon']`, I would like to determine a reference grid point `ref_grid_point` and select all grid points within a radius of `X` grid points from the reference.

If I have lat/lon in degrees, one could directly consider the degree values as `radius` (`ds.sel(lat = slice(ref_grid_point['lat'] + radius, ref_grid_point['lat'] - radius), lon = slice(ref_grid_point['lon'] - radius, ref_grid_point['lon'] + radius))`).

However, in my case, I would like to have the grid points instead of the degree value (integers as 1,2,n grid points from the reference).

Comment: how is this any different from the case of distance in degrees, but just accounting for the grid spacing? or are you on some sort of irregular grid? if so, can you provide more info about your problem, ideally as a [mre]?

Comment: The grid is regular. Ideally I wanted to change the distance from the standard degrees to X grid points, but I haven't found this option in the documentation.

Comment: there is no such option. I'm just wondering if you could just multiply the number of grid points by the grid spacing to achieve the same effect. e.g. if you want 3 cells in a 0.25 degree grid, couldn't you just use 0.75?

Comment: That is of course possible, but I wanted to keep it more agnostic to the resolution of the data, as I would like to use this on different datasets (eg: select a squared grid with central point + neighbor points regardless of the resolution).